# Get an element in Json using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, casting

I have this JSON and I want to get this part: '1000000007296871' in SQL

```
{"pixel_rule":"{\"and\":[{\"event\":{\"eq\":\"Purchase\"}},{\"or\":[{\"content_ids\":{\"i_contains\":\"1000000007296871\"}}]}]}"}
```

How to do that?
this is JSON Dump

Comment: Your JSON data looks really strange. What exactly is the data type of that column?

Comment: that's JSON, i have check with SELECT COLUMN_TYPE, not all are nested like this @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: `json` or `json[]`?

Comment: it show `json`  @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: `Json dump` let me correct  @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my option is using `regex`
'\d+' if other part is not digit

```
select substring('string' from '\d+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this like so:

```
SELECT
(
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    '{"pixel_rule":"{\"and\":[{\"event\":{\"eq\":\"Purchase\"}},{\"or\":[{\"content_ids\":{\"i_contains\":\"1000000007296871\"}}]}]}"}'::json->>'pixel_rule'
                )::json->>'and'
            )::json->1
        )::json->>'or'
    )::json->0->>'content_ids'
)::json->>'i_contains';
```

But something is really funny about your input, since it contains json nested in json multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be smoothing the object by trimming the wrapper quotes of the `pixel_rule`'s value, and then getting rid of redundant backslashes, and applying `json_array_elements` function consecutively in order to use `#>>` operator with the related path to extract the desired value :

```
SELECT json_array_elements
       (
        json_array_elements(
           replace(trim((jsdata #>'{pixel_rule}')::text,'"'),'\','')::json -> 'and'
        ) -> 'or'
       )::json #>> '{content_ids,i_contains}' AS "Value"
  FROM tab
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1659d455fb63a10620e12ee0c8e6d183)</kbd>